# How to assign more than 1 ip to a Virtualbox machine?

Tags: virtual-machines, virtualbox

how would I assign 3 ips to one instance of a Virtualbox machine (Ubuntu 10.04)? I need to for development purposes.

Comment: ... the same way you would assign more than one IP to any other kind of machine (disable DHCP in the guest OS and assign the addresses manually.  I'm not sure what you're asking here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Virtual box allows you to assign 4 network adapters to a particular machine. In virtual Box Manager go to the machine and in the settings pane click on networking. You should be able to attach 2 more adapters from there.

Comment: @Darren - your comment indicates that what you asked and what you wanted are two different things. Adding more network adapters gives you more IP addresses, but network adapters and IP addresses are two different things when it comes to assigning more of them. You can assign more IP addresses without assigning more adapters.

Answer (score 2):

Inside Ubuntu, you can use the `ip` command to add IP addresses to an interface. Example: assign IP address 10.0.0.2 to the network interface eth0:

```
sudo ip addr add 10.0.0.2 dev eth0
```

If you decide to remove it:

```
sudo ip addr del 10.0.0.2 dev eth0
```